# Screen goes black when I play Infinity Blade

Tags: ios, infinity-blade, technical-issues, game-center

I was playing Infinity Blade on my iPhone 4 and I selected game center option to look at my achievements and when I push the "Done" button, the screen went black.  I exited the app and went back it is still black.

How do I fix this issue and return to the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the app is still black is likely because it is still running. Try exiting to your Springboard (home screen) and double-tapping the home button, bringing up the multitasking bar. Find Infinity Blade, and hold down your finger on the icon. They will start to wobble, like you are rearranging apps. Press the little minus icon on the Infinity Blade icon - this quits the app. Tap anywhere on your home screen to return, and try launching Infinity Blade again.